# How to save multiple files in Android

Tags: file, android-studio, save

Here I want to save multiple files in android(internal or external storage). I have used a way to save file. It saves only the last file. Not the all files. Can you please check this and if there are any changes please comment here

[image: Here is the code of the saving file that I've used]

Comment: Add the code as text rather than an image

Comment: I don't understand the issue? You are only trying to save one file in the code (`mysdfile`).

Comment: Guys I found a solution for this issue. Thanks for your great effort

Comment: If you found a solution then why not share it? You have the option to answer your own question.